# ArcGIS API for JavaScript - Export as Geotiff

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

I have a web application using ArcGIS API for Javascript. I am trying to implement a widget in order to export GEOTIFFs based on the users display. The format is not limited to tiffs, but the geographic component is crucial for this widget. This could then be brought into various platforms for use as a georeferenced image. The closest widget I could find only exports an image without geographic information attached: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/samples/widget_print/

Unfortunately, this has to be done within this API.

Anyone know where to go from here?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of box solution for this. If you dont have any graphics on the map, you could create you own Geoprocessing service which takes in the extent you wish to export and get the required Geotiff file. If you have Production Mapping extension you could do that
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/production-mapping/exporting-to-layout-geotiff.htm

Also you can find some information here https://geonet.esri.com/thread/32020

The most simple solution would be to create a World File(.tfw) along with Tiff images. TFW files are simple ascii file and all they contain is 6 parameters. The format of TFW files can be found her. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will explore this option!